# How to convert string "[date] [time] to [time]" to two datetimes in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

Given a string which will always match a pattern like this

```
07-Dec-2016 5:15PM to 5:30PM
```

What is the cleanest way to use PHP to create two datetimes ready for MySQL of the format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm-ss`?

Let to my own devices, I would build something clumsy with `substr` but I believe PHP can be intuitive with dates?

Ideally:

```
function convertTimeGiven($timeString) {
     // some great code

     return $times;
}

echo convertTimeGiven($timeString)['start']; //output 2016-12-07 17:15:00
echo convertTimeGiven($timeString)['end'];   //output 2016-12-07 17:30:00
```

Comment: How does it look when an event started at 23:50 and ended at 00:20?

Comment: @GeorgyIvanov Nice thought. Add one day, simple. I have added that code as well. `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this way:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/plain");
    $dateTime = "07-Dec-2016 5:15PM to 5:30PM";
    $dateTime = str_replace(" to ", " ", $dateTime);
    $dateTime = explode(" ", $dateTime);
    print_r($dateTime);
    $date1 = strtotime("{$dateTime[0]} {$dateTime[1]}");
    $date2 = strtotime("{$dateTime[0]} {$dateTime[2]}");
    print_r(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date1));
    print_r(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date2));
?>
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 07-Dec-2016
    [1] => 5:15PM
    [2] => 5:30PM
)
2016-12-07 5:15 pm
2016-12-07 5:30 pm
```

**Functional Representation**

For your function:

```
<?php
    function convertTimeGiven($dateTime) {
        $dateTime = str_replace(" to ", " ", $dateTime);
        $dateTime = explode(" ", $dateTime);
        $date1 = strtotime("{$dateTime[0]} {$dateTime[1]}");
        $date2 = strtotime("{$dateTime[0]} {$dateTime[2]}");
        return array(
            "start" => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date1),
            "end" => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date2)
        );
    }
?>
```

**Output**

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/plain");
    $dateTime = "07-Dec-2016 5:15PM to 5:30PM";
    function convertTimeGiven($dateTime) {
        $dateTime = str_replace(" to ", " ", $dateTime);
        $dateTime = explode(" ", $dateTime);
        $date1 = strtotime("{$dateTime[0]} {$dateTime[1]}");
        $date2 = strtotime("{$dateTime[0]} {$dateTime[2]}");
        return array(
            "start" => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date1),
            "end" => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date2)
        );
    }
    print_r(convertTimeGiven($dateTime));
?>
```

```
Array
(
    [start] => 2016-12-07 5:15 pm
    [end] => 2016-12-07 5:30 pm
)
```

**Involvement of Two days**

**Note:** You need to manually add one day, if the event ends after 12 am.

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/plain");
    $dateTime = "07-Dec-2016 11:15PM to 12:30AM";
    function convertTimeGiven($dateTime) {
        $dateTime = str_replace(" to ", " ", $dateTime);
        $dateTime = explode(" ", $dateTime);
        $date1 = strtotime("{$dateTime[0]} {$dateTime[1]}");
        $date2 = strtotime("{$dateTime[0]} {$dateTime[2]}");
        if ($date1 > $date2)
            $date2 = strtotime("{$dateTime[0]} {$dateTime[2]} + 1 day");
        return array(
            "start" => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date1),
            "end" => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date2)
        );
    }
    print_r(convertTimeGiven($dateTime));
?>
```

Comment: Perfect - thank you. Small edit for me - I'll output `H:i:s` rather than your `g:i a`

Comment: @Warren Yea, sure... Just added the second part. Did you see?

Comment: @Warren Updated answer. Glad I could help... `:)`

Comment: I did - fantastic!! I'll never have two days, but I'll use that function to cover myself.

Comment: @Warren Ha ha.. Some one challenged in the OP comments. So I thought of adding it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it will do:

```
function convertTimeGiven($timeString) {
     $date_start = substr($timeString, 0, 18);       
     $data_end = substr($timeString, 0, 12) . substr($timeString, -7);

     $time_start = strtotime($date_start);
     $time_end = strtotime($data_end);

     if($time_start > $time_end)
     {
        $time_end = strtotime("+1 day", $time_end);
     }

     $times = array(
        'start' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time_start),
        'end' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time_end)
     );

     return $times;
}
```

It returns in the military time, as you expected.

`Array ( [start] => 2016-12-07 17:15:00 [end] => 2016-12-07 17:30:00 )` for `07-Dec-2016 5:15PM to 5:30PM`

and

`Array ( [start] => 2016-12-07 17:15:00 [end] => 2016-12-08 00:30:00 )` for `07-Dec-2016 5:15PM to 12:30AM`

Comment: Yup, but this will not calculate the second day.

Answer (score 0):

This is the cleanest I could get :)

```
<?php
function convertTimeGiven($timeString) {
    $inputFormat = 'd-M-Y H:iA';
    $outputFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
    $exploded = explode(' to', $timeString);
    $start = \DateTime::createFromFormat($inputFormat, $exploded[0]);
    $end = \DateTime::createFromFormat($inputFormat, $start->format('d-M-Y') . $exploded[1]);
    return [
        'start' => $start->format($outputFormat),
        'end' => $end->format($outputFormat)
    ];
}
```

**Note**, however, that the problem with "next day" still exists. Answer posted by Praveen Kumar handles "next day problem" only applies if the timespan ends in 'AM'.

If you input something like `07-Dec-2016 5:15PM to 4:30PM` or `07-Dec-2016 5:15PM to 6:30PM` we cannot determine when that took place.